# How to display specified date from numeric value to Lithuanian format?

Tags: datetime

I'm unable to understand how to specify a date something like `06-09-2012` (or any other numeric equivalent) so it would print it in Lithuanian? There's package called `[lithuanian]{babel}` and for example `\today` works fine. But I don't need today's date, I need specific date which would be converted to `\longdate` format and translated to Lithuanian. I've tried various variants, sometimes it says that there's no weekday and month defined for Lithuanian language. But why `\today` works? If it's really true, so then how can I add those weekdays manually in my document, without hacking library itself?

Comment: `datetime` doesn't provide any support for Lithuanian and as `datetime` is no longer maintained, no new languages will be added to it. A better option is to switch to `datetime2` and add your own Lithuanian module, which can be done without hacking the base package. There's information on how to do this in the [datetime2 manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf) near the end of the section "Multi-lingual Support". The simplest method is to just adapt an existing language module that closest matches the Lithuanian format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why \today works?

In the kernel and with packages like `babel` or `polyglossia`, `\today` is hard-coded using `\day` (the current day of month) `\month` (the current month number) and `\year` (the year). For example, the default definition is

```
\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or 
June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or 
December\fi \space \number \day , \number \year
```

A cheap hack is to temporarily redefine `\day`, `\month` and `\year` if you want a specific date. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{lithuanian}

\newcommand*{\anotherday}[3]{%
  {% scope
    \def\year{#1}%
    \def\month{#2}%
    \def\day{#3}%
    \today
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\anotherday{1999}{12}{31}

\today

\end{document}
```

This won't work in contexts where the date needs expanding. For example, in PDF bookmarks (if you're using `hyperref`) or if you want to write a date stamp to an external file. It would also need protection in a moving argument.

Ideally, it's better for `\today` to use a date formatting command that takes the day, month and year as arguments. This formatting command could then be used for specific dates. The `datetime` package does this by robustly redefining `\today` as:

```
\formatdate{\day}{\month}{\year}
```

Whereas `datetime2` does this by non-robustly redefining `\today` as:

```
\DTMdisplaydate{\@dtm@currentyear}{\@dtm@currentmonth}{\@dtm@currentday}{\@dtm@currentdow}
```

This doesn't use `\year`, `\month` and `\day`, but instead uses its own internal storage commands, including the day of week index (which defaults to `-1`, but the `datetime2-calc` package will compute it using commands provided by `pgfcalendar`).

In the case of `datetime`, the formatting command `\formatdate` is redefined by the date styles. The language styles are provided in the files `dt-`*language*`.def`. The provided `.def` files are:

```
dt-american.def    dt-croatian.def   dt-greek.def       dt-ngerman.def   dt-slovene.def
dt-australian.def  dt-czech.def      dt-hebrew.def      dt-norsk.def     dt-spanish.def
dt-austrian.def    dt-danish.def     dt-icelandic.def   dt-polish.def    dt-swedish.def
dt-bahasa.def      dt-dutch.def      dt-irish.def       dt-portuges.def  dt-turkish.def
dt-basque.def      dt-esperanto.def  dt-italian.def     dt-romanian.def  dt-UKenglish.def
dt-breton.def      dt-estonian.def   dt-latin.def       dt-russian.def   dt-ukraineb.def
dt-british.def     dt-finnish.def    dt-lsorbian.def    dt-samin.def     dt-USenglish.def
dt-bulgarian.def   dt-french.def     dt-magyar.def      dt-scottish.def  dt-usorbian.def
dt-canadian.def    dt-galician.def   dt-naustrian.def   dt-serbian.def   dt-welsh.def
dt-catalan.def     dt-german.def     dt-newzealand.def  dt-slovak.def
```

This doesn't include a file for Lithuanian. Adding a new supported language requires not only a new `.def` file but also a modification to `datetime.sty`.

The `datetime2` package, which replaces `datetime`, also uses styles to redefine `\DTMdisplaydate`. There are some numeric styles available in the base `datetime2.sty` code, but the language and regional styles are provided in independently maintained `.ldf` files. Unlike `datetime`, the `.ldf` files can be added without any modification to the base `datetime2.sty` code. This makes it easier for users to add support for their own language or region. A [search of CTAN](http://ctan.org/search/?phrase=datetime2) will list all supported languages.

If your language isn't supported, here are some instructions on how to add it.

There are two basic types of `datetime2` `.ldf` files:

- Regionless language-only support. For example, [`datetime2-scottish`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-scottish), which only provides the date styles `scottish` and `scottish-numeric`.
- Support for a particular combination of language and region. For example, [`datetime2-english`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english), which provides the regionless `english` style (matches the kernel definition of `\today`) but also a number of regional styles. At the time of writing these are:

  - `en-GB` (English - United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland)
  - `en-US` (English - United States of America)
  - `en-CA` (English - Canada)
  - `en-AU` (English - Commonwealth of Australia)
  - `en-NZ` (English - New Zealand)
  - `en-GG` (English - Bailiwick of Guernsey)
  - `en-JE` (English - Bailiwick of Jersey)
  - `en-IM` (English - Isle of Man)
  - `en-MT` (English - Republic of Malta)
  - `en-IE` (English - Republic of Ireland)

  These not only change the way `\DTMdisplaydate` behaves but also set the time zone mappings. For example, the `en-GB` style displays UTC+1 as `BST` whereas the `en-IE` style displays it as `IST` when the time zone mappings are on.

The date styles provided for languages with extended Latin or non-Latin characters have two versions: *language*`-ascii.ldf` and *language*`-utf8.ldf`. The `ascii` version uses LaTeX commands, such as `\'`, to produce the non-ASCII characters. The `utf8` version uses UTF-8 characters. This means that XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX users can conveniently write the date to an external non-TeX file in an easy to read format.

Some styles may also provide different alphabets. For example, [`datetime2-serbian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-serbian) has Cyrillic and Latin options and provides `\DTMserbiancyrmonthname` for the Cyrillic month names and `\DTMserbianlatinmonthname` for the Latin month names. The default month names are provided by `\DTMserbianmonthname` which is initialised to `\DTMserbiancyrmonthname`. The `alphabet` setting redefines `\DTMserbianmonthname`.

If you want to provide support for a new language, the simplest thing is to find an existing style and modify it as appropriate.

For example, I'm going to base it on the `german` style (because that has UTF-8 support) with some modifications. So download [`datetime2-german.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/datetime2-german/datetime2-german.dtx) and save it as `datetime2-lithuanian.dtx`, download [`datetime2-german.ins`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/datetime2-german/datetime2-german.ins) and save it as `datetime2-lithuanian.ins` and download [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/datetime2-german/README).

In each of these three files, do the following case-sensitive global search and replace (make sure your editor is set to UTF-8):

- `german` -> `lithuanian`
- `German` -> `Lithuanian`

(If you want to upload it to [CTAN](http://ctan.org/), which would be helpful to others, then change the version number and dates as appropriate, as well as the maintainer's name and the documentation. Make sure you set the [line endings to LF](http://ctan.org/file/help/ctan/CTAN-upload-addendum).)

In the file `datetime2-lithuanian.dtx`, search for `<*datetime2-lithuanian-utf8.ldf>`. This is the start of the UTF-8 support. The first command is

```
\newcommand*{\DTMlithuanianordinal}[1]{%
  \number#1
}
```

This is the way the day of month number is displayed. I don't know any Lithuanian, but I'm guessing from the way `polyglossia` displays the date that this should be `\number#1~d.` so make the appropriate change here.

Is the `m.` part of the month name or a year suffix? If it's a year suffix, add

```
%\begin{macro}{\DTMlithuanianyear}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*{\DTMlithuanianyear}[1]{%
  \number#1 m.%
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
```

otherwise it goes in the next command, which is `\DTMlithuanianmonthname`. Replace the month names as appropriate using UTF-8 characters. There is also a version `\DTMlithuanianMonthname` where the first letter is in upper case. This is in case the month needs to be displayed at the start of a sentence. Replace the month names as appropriate.

If you want to support week day names, you also need `\DTMlithuanianweekdayname`. This should be in the form (replace the English names with the appropriate translations):

```
%\begin{macro}{\DTMlithuanianweekdayname}
% Day of week names.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*{\DTMlithuanianweekdayname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  Monday%
  \or
  Tuesday%
  \or
  Wednesday%
  \or
  Thursday%
  \or
  Friday%
  \or
  Saturday%
  \or
  Sunday%
  \fi
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
```

Similarly provide `\DTMlithuanianWeekdayname` for the first letter upper case variant.

If you want to provide support for abbreviations, similarly define `\DTMlithuanianshortmonthname`, `\DTMlithuanianshortMonthname`, `\DTMlithuanianshortweekdayname` and `\DTMlithuanianshortWeekdayname`.

The next section of the `.dtx` file is `<*datetime2-lithuanian-ascii.ldf>`. Do the same as the above, but use LaTeX commands instead of UTF-8 characters.

The next section is `<*datetime2-lithuanian.ldf>` which provides the new date styles. There are two styles: a textual style called `lithuanian` and a numeric style called `lithuanian-numeric`. This first provides some commands that allow the styles to be configurable within `\DTMlangsetup`. These will need changing to match your language's style. For example, the separator between the month and day in the textual style can be defined as:

```
\newcommand*{\DTMlithuanianmonthdaysep}{%
 \DTMtexorpdfstring{\protect~}{\space}%
}
```

and the corresponding key for `\DTMlangsetup` is defined using:

```
\DTMdefkey{lithuanian}{monthdaysep}{\renewcommand*{\DTMlithuanianmonthdaysep}{#1}}
```

Boolean settings are defined using `\DTMdefboolkey`. For example:

```
\DTMdefboolkey{lithuanian}{showdayofmonth}[true]{}
```

and they can be set using `\DTMsetbool`. For example:

```
\DTMsetbool{lithuanian}{showdayofmonth}{true}
```

The actual styles are defined using `\DTMnewstyle`. These need to redefine `\DTMdisplaydate` and (for the start of a sentence) `\DTMDisplaydate`. These both have four arguments: the year (`##1`), the month number (`##2`), the day of month number (`##3`) and the day of week index (`##4`).

If you have defined `\DTMlithuanianyear` this needs to be applied to the year. For example:

```
\DTMlithuanianyear{##1}%
```

Otherwise, just use `\number`:

```
\number##1 % space intended
```

The boolean keys can be accessed using `\DTMifbool`. For example, to determine whether or not the day of the month should be displayed:

```
 \DTMifbool{lithuanian}{showdayofmonth}
 {\DTMlithuanianmonthdaysep\DTMlithuanianordinal{##3}}%
 {}%
```

The global `showdow` setting can be queried using `\ifDTMshowdow` if you want to provide week day name support. Note that if the day of week index is set to `-1`, then the week day name should be omitted regardless of the `showdow` setting. For example, the `en-GB` style in `datetime2-english.dtx` has:

```
 \ifDTMshowdow
   \ifnum##4>-1
    \DTMifbool{en-GB}{abbr}%
     {\DTMenglishshortweekdayname{##4}}%
     {\DTMenglishweekdayname{##4}}%
    \DTMenGBdowdaysep
   \fi
 \fi
```

This queries the `showdow` setting (`\ifDTMshowdow`), and then it checks that the week day index is non-negative (`\ifnum##4>-1`). This includes support for the abbreviated names. The boolean `abbr` key can be defined with:

```
\DTMdefboolkey{lithuanian}{abbr}[true]{}
\DTMsetbool{lithuanian}{abbr}{false}
```

and the separator between the week day name and the day of month number:

```
\newcommand*{\DTMlithuaniandowdaysep}{\space}
```

So the Lithuanian code would include

```
 \ifDTMshowdow
   \ifnum##4>-1
    \DTMifbool{lithuanian}{abbr}%
     {\DTMlithuanianshortweekdayname{##4}}%
     {\DTMlithuanianweekdayname{##4}}%
    \DTMlithuaniandowdaysep
   \fi
 \fi
```

(Naturally you'll need to modify this if the week day name should come after the day of month number.)

Once you have made all the relevant changes, the `.ldf` files can be extracted using:

```
latex datetime2-lithuanian.ins
```

For the documented code use:

```
pdflatex datetime2-lithuanian.dtx
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a code like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}

\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}

Date in long format so that language variations are prominent.

Today's date: \today.

Now, let us set a new date.

\newdate{ld}{6}{9}{2012}

And display it.

\displaydate{ld}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for patience @Masroor. In the end it displays: "Thursday 6 September, 2012", although today's date shows in Lithuanian. After documentclass, I've added `\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}` or else it says `Error: Encoding scheme L7x unknown.` I'm using TeXnicle app with MacTex 5gb installation :)